# Couchbase adding quotes to Spatialviewrows Value

Tags: python, return-value, geospatial, couchbase, bounding-box

I wrote a geospatialview in Couchbase:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.type == 'Bar') {
    if(doc.position) {
      emit(
          {
             type: "Point",
             coordinates: [doc.position.latitude, doc.position.longitude]
          }, doc.companyID);
    }
  }
}
```

I then try to get them via a bounding box. Couchbase correctly returns the objects within this box. I want to emit the companyID as value and compare it to another String to find out if the request is permitted.

The problem is i get the value emited like this in unicode:

```
u'''CM-dummycompany'''
```

The comparestring I got from another cbobject like this:

```
u'CM-dummycompany'
```

When i compare these too it fails.
So any idea how to compare the right way?

I tried it with `==` and `is`. I also tried to cast it into string and then compare, but this fails obviously because I have nonconform characters like `äöü`

Or better question, why are double quotes added to the emitted value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution in the Couchbase issue Tracker:

[Spatial views return value is double encoded](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-12093?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)

So for everyone who is also facing this problem:
The issue is, that in spatial views, the value gets double encoded. This means that if you return a number it becomes a string. And a string becomes a string with escaped quotes.

Actually they say it is already fixed in 3.0.1 but I already updated and the problem still exists.

My workaround was just to remove the quotes via `re`:

```
value = re.sub('"','',value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just know that as of this posting Geospatial views in Couchbase are considered experimental and not production ready. Official support isn't scheduled to come until at least the next two major releases.